# changing li class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this snippet of jQuery code:

```
$("#cf_state_chosen.chosen-container.chosen-container-single div.chosen-drop ul.chosen-results li").each( function(i) {
    console.log( $("#cf_state_chosen.chosen-container.chosen-container-single div.chosen-drop ul.chosen-results li")[i] );
});
```

It will output the following:

```
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">AL</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">AK</li>
<li class="active-result result-selected" style="" data-option-array-index="3">AZ</li>
<li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">AR</li>
```

The `result-selected` changes when the user selects a different state from a `select` dropdown box.  How can I programmatically preset this?  I will pull the state from another input field which is populated via an ajax jQuery call.

How can I also remove `result-selected` if it happens to be set for an outdated choice?

Answer (score 1):

For removing,checking,adding class there is three method in jquery

> [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Try like this

```
$("li[class*='result-selected']").each(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("result-selected");
});
$("#cf_state_chosen.chosen-container.chosen-container-single div.chosen-drop ul.chosen-results li").each( function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("result-selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing any outdated choices can be accomplished by selecting all elements with "result-selected" class, and then removing this specific class:

```
$('.result-selected').removeClass('result-selected');
```

And, supposing your `<select>` has an `id="stateSelector"`, you could:

```
$('#stateSelector').val('FL'); //<== setting the Select choice to the one with 'FL' value (value and not text!)
```

If not, you can select it by a class or anything that can identify that specific select apart from any other. Just watch out for using the value of the option and not the text.